# How to set dynamic resque queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, resque

I wish I could decide on which queue to go to work.
This is because if the job is scheduled by the server (cronjob) it must be run on a slow queue, if instead it is run by the user it will go on a fast queue. 
How can I run this in Resque?

**Controller**

```
MyJob.perform_later(id, :fast)
```

**Rake task**

```
MyJob.perform_later(id, :slow)
```

**Job**

```
class MyJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default #<-- This has to be dynamic

  def perform(item_id, queue_name)
     ....
  end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see you are using `ActiveJob`, you can set the queue by using `set` method:

**Controller**

```rb
MyJob.set(queue: :fast).perform_later(id)
```

**Rake task**

```rb
MyJob.set(queue: :slow).perform_later(id)
```

`set` method allows you to set more thing than just queue, you can also set eg priority or when should job be performed. See the documentation https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveJob/Core/ClassMethods.html#method-i-set

*Note: I presume, you already have slow and fast Resque queues in place and running and only want to use them*